# I was banned for a week for something frightening innocuous

Tags: discussion

[What are the differences between sex cults and the tantric tradition?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/39903/what-are-the-differences-between-sex-cults-and-the-tantric-tradition/39905#39905)

One "bad" question or answer over like seven years. What is even bad about it? Do you disagree with what it says, or are you just trying to humiliate me for a lack of references?

I also lost 700 bounty and the wrong answers were given bounty, due to this.

Comment: I for one think it was too harsh. I also put a lot of effort into that answer for the bounty. It is imo legitimate question but not a very good one because of the semantics. It would be good if they gave you back the reputation. I don't mind your answer to the question neither, doesn't bother me one bit even tho i don't agree with it.

Comment: 7 days for basically asking about the particulars of Buddhist sex cults and posting an answer half-heartedly. What happened to just voting down things and they didn't even delete neither the answer nor the question because they don't really violate anything. I think they just banned you because they felt you needed to 'cool down' tbh

Comment: It is actually a very interesting act of moderation. Instead of moderating the content they moderate the person. You don't really break any rules but we ban you anyway just because your answer is not good enough? I don't know if there was another reason for this decision and who banned you but i am quite intetested in finding out.

Comment: I think you should complain to SE management if it's not settled here

Comment: likely to just wind up any site i bring this up in haha. thanks tho @MAGA2020

Answer (score 1):

We are looking for high-quality answers that adhere to the policy on [*"How to write a good answer"*](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

As seen in the screenshot below, the original posted answer, was lazy and of low-quality/effort.

[image]

Try to make an effort to write to the best of your ability when posting questions and answers.

To be fair, banning you for one week without a warning, was too harsh. If it happens again in the future, I will give you a warning.

The reputation and bounty cannot be refunded or undone. That's just how the system works.
If you like, I can offer 700 of my own reputation and place it according to your wishes.

I hope to see you on the site in the future.

Comment: i don't see what the original answer shows except a willingness to improve the answer

Comment: On what ground do you warn/ban people who give bad answers? what exactly is a bad answer? Is wrong answer a bad answer? If wrong answer isn't in and by itself a bad answer, must the answer look aesthetically pleasing to be good? Would be good to get some clear guidelines on how to make the answers good so we don't all get banned.

Comment: @MAGA2020 What's considered "good" and "bad" might usually be assessed/expressed by [voting](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) though that's an imperfect measure. A bad answer might merely downvoted or not-upvoted (with a moderator's intervening e.g. to delete it if it seems hostile, off-topic, trolling, disruptive, etc.). Self-answered questions in particular might be unpopular too, unless the OP is careful to fit in with other users' answers etc., and/or to write high-quality questions and answers.

Comment: I generally wouldn't suspend a user unless they're exceptionally rude -- or for a pattern of repeated misbehaviour, and then/that only after a warning. In fact according to you I don't suspend users easily enough (but that's a different story).

Comment: Is it normal/acceptable to ban people for bad answers? Is it so that 1st you get a warning, then if you keep posting bad answers you get banned?

Comment: @MAGA2020 Maybe "it's rare in practice but not impossible in theory on other sites", and, "that's not normal on this site". I'm trying to remember cases where a user account was ever temporarily suspended on this site: if it does ever happen normally -- which is rare but not unheard of -- that more likely to be with a brand-new user, e.g. I might blow away nonsense from an unregistered user and block the user too if it was semi-hostile. That said this isn't supposed to be, "can I write lots of bad answers without being suspended?". Downvoted answers in general aren't very common on this site.